# Is there a projective morphism from the quadric surface to the projective plane with degree 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Is there a projective morphism from the quadric surface $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ to the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$, with degree $1$?

Comment: over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev yes, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in any characteristic. Let $f:\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1=X\to Y=\mathbb{P}^2$ be such a morphism. Then, the map can not be finite, since it is of degree one and $Y$ is smooth would imply that $f$ is an isomorphism. This is not true by Picard group considerations or many other considerations.

So, one must have an irreducible curve $E\subset X$ such that $f(E)=\mathrm{point}$. This implies $E^2<0$ (by Hodge index theorem), but looking at intersection form on $X$, easy to see that there can not be such a curve.

Comment: Dear Mohan, your  assertion in the first section that $f$ would be an isomorphism if finite of degree one with $Y$ smooth is true, but I can only prove it by invoking Zariski's Main Theorem. Do you have a simpler argument  in mind? Anyway, +1.

Comment: Dear Georges Elencwajg, I would argue as follows. Since $f$ is proper, if it has finite fibers, then it is finite and since both $X,Y$ are smooth, the map is flat. Then $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is locally free, but degree one implies it is is of rank one. Using the split map $\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, we see that the latter is just $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and for a finite map, this implies isomorphism.